# Stored procedure 'sp_oledb_columns' not found

Tags: c#, sql-server, sap-ase

I have a table in MSSQL SERVER that i want to do a bulk copy to SYBASE 12.5 using ASE client, but i keep getting this error "Stored procedure 'sp_oledb_columns' not found". How do i solve this?

This is my code

```
using (AseConnection theCons = new AseConnection(connstring))
            {    
if (theCons.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        theCons.Open();
                    }

                    AseBulkCopy objbulk = new AseBulkCopy(theCons);

                    objbulk.DestinationTableName = "dbo.itb_payment_upload";
                    objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add(new AseBulkCopyColumnMapping() { SourceColumn = "from_acct_no", DestinationColumn = "from_acct_no" });
                    objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add(new AseBulkCopyColumnMapping() { SourceColumn = "to_acct_no", DestinationColumn = "to_acct_no" });
                    objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add(new AseBulkCopyColumnMapping() { SourceColumn = "Itbid", DestinationColumn = "RecordId" });


                    try
                    {
                        objbulk.WriteToServer(dt); //where dt is my DataTable from my source table
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {

                    }
}
```

Comment: What is `theCons`?

Comment: You are not referencing sp_oledb_columns in ur code.

Comment: @ChrisPickford theCons is my connection string (AseConnection) to sybase.

Comment: @Musfiqur rahman where am i to reference the stored procedure sp_oledb_columns from?

Comment: Probably this link help you http://www.sqlbrowser.com/wikiHTML/sqlbhtml/sybsystemprocs/sp_oledb_columns.html

Comment: @AlexKudryashev thanks got it from there with other supporting table(s) like spt_sybdrv

Answer (score 0):

This procedure called by `AseBulkCopy` (through `connection.GetSchema("columns")`) to load target table columns metadata.
Not sure 12.5 has this procedure, and even if it exists, it will not be compatible with provider, so you need to recreate it using code from sqlbrowser.com if you want to use bulk copy.